# Certain Android Devices Not Rendering ViewPager / Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am using AWS device farm to test the appearance of my home page on all devices that run Android.

My basic home screen is a main activity that hosts a viewpager. For some odd reason, some of the devices in the AWS test are not loading the viewpager (they appear to be samsung galaxy devices and a few other makes/models as well).

I know the activity is loading because I have separate titles in the action bar for the hosting activity and each fragment in the viewpager.

I am trying to at least get an idea of a possible cause to further investigate. My initial inclination would be to check the Min SDK I am supporting, and I have it set at 16 in my build.gradle.

Any thoughts or input would be appreciated.